# Properly align Css boxes

Tags: html, css, django

I have boxes that wouldnt align properly. Some of them are 40px higher than others, and have remove icon as you can see in the picture:
[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NeqI.png)

If all boxes are the same height then boxes would align properly:
[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMfym.png)

Unfortunately i cannot make them all the same height. I want to align them properly, without changing height. I know that there will be some margin differences because of diferent height but that is okay.
Here is code for the boxes:

```
.parents-parent {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.parent {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
    margin: 10px;
    min-height: 150px;
  }
  .exam-box-el {
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .exam-box-el:hover {
    background-color: rgb(247,247,247);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .parent a {
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  }
  .parent a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  }
  .parent .glyphicon {
    margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
  }
  .more {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(210,210,210);
  }
  .exam-title {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: ;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .exam-title a {
    color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
  }
  .exam-title a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
  }
```

and html:

```
<div class="parents-parent">
{% for exam in exams %}

<div class="parent" exam-id="{{ exam.pk }}" csrf="{{ csrf_token }}">

<div class="exam-title">
<a><b>Test številka {{ exam.exam_number }}</b></a>
</div>

<a class="exam-span-wrapper">
<div class="exam-box-el  exam-span-file">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Test
</div>

<ul class="exam-ul">
{% for file in exam.examfile_set.all %}
<li class="exam-li-img" src="{{ file.exam_file.url }}" alt="Slika Testa" width="60" height="60" class="img-resposive exam-img">Slika Testa {{ forloop.counter }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

</a>

<a class="comment">
<div class="exam-box-el"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Komentarji
</div>
</a>

<a class="mark-exam">
  <div class="exam-box-el">
      <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Potrebno popravka" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle {% if user in exam.exam_mark.all %}active{% endif %}"></span> Potrebno popravka
  </div>
</a>

<a href="{% url 'profile' exam.exam_user %}">
<div class="exam-box-el"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>{{ exam.exam_user }}
</div>
</a> 

{% if exam.exam_user == user %}

<a href="#" class="remove-exam">
<div class="exam-box-el more">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyphicon-remove-exam"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Izbriši"></span>
 Odstrani
</div>
</a>
{% endif %}

</div>


{% endfor %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.parents-parent { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }` and remove the `float` from `.parent`. That will create flex rows and each item will stretch to match the height of the parent.

Or if you're always going to have 3 cells per row, you can use `:nth-child()` on the floated cells to clear the left floats on every 3rd element. You would do that by adding `.parent:nth-child(3n + 1) { clear: left; }`

Comment: thats almost it! Is there any way to not stretch the shorter divs, just fill in the margin? Right now it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/3hnm3Bw.png

Comment: @lagtri did you try my 2nd approach?